# How to install Mezzanine on Webfaction Server

Tags: django, webfaction, mezzanine

I've been choosing a django CMS for my personal site, and I decided that Mezzanine would be the one that most satisfies my needs. But I find it impossible for me to install it on Webfaction. There's all kinds of errors going on, and for a noob like me it's very frustrating. I followed this awesome guide, http://ijcdigital.com/blog/installing-django-mezzanine-at-webfaction/, which is probably written a year ago. Unfortunately, I simply can't get it working by following that guide. So could anyone provide me a more up-to-date and easy to follow guide for installing Mezzanine on Webfaction?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install Mezzanine on a WebFaction hosting account, first create a new PostgreSQL database via the WF control panel, and make a note of the database name and password.

Next, create a  "Django 1.6.10 (mod_wsgi 3.5/Python 2.7)" application and assign it to a website.

Next, SSH into your server and run the following commands (replacing `name_of_your_app`, `database_name`, `database_password`, and `my_cms` with appropriate values):

```
mkdir -p ~/lib/python2.7
easy_install-2.7 pip
cd ~/webapps/name_of_your_app
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/lib/python2.7
pip2.7 install -U --install-option="--install-scripts=$PWD/bin" --install-option="--install-lib=$PWD/lib/python2.7" mezzanine
~/bin/mezzanine-project my_cms
cd my_cms
sed -i 's/"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3"/"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"/g' local_settings.py
sed -i 's/"NAME": "dev.db"/"NAME": "database_name"/g' local_settings.py
sed -i 's/"USER": ""/"USER": "database_name"/g' local_settings.py
sed -i 's/"PASSWORD": ""/"PASSWORD": "database_password"/g' local_settings.py
sed -i 's/DEBUG = True/DEBUG = False/g' local_settings.py
echo "ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yourdomain.com',]" >> local_settings.py
python2.7 manage.py createdb --noinput
python2.7 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
sed -i 's/myproject\/myproject\/wsgi.py/my_cms\/wsgi.py/g' ../apache2/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i 's/myproject/my_cms/g' ../apache2/conf/httpd.conf
../apache2/bin/restart
```

Next, create a "Symbolic link to static-only app" in the control panel, using "`/home/your_username/webapps/name_of_your_app/my_cms/static`" as the symlink path (in the "extra info" field, then assign that app to your site, using '`/static`' as the URL path.

Then just wait a few minutes for that last change to gel, and you're done.

Comment: Wow, this guide is awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: This helped me move forward, but it's not quite correct.  If you have trouble, you may want to make your database name and database user are the same, run 'pip-2.7 install -r requirements.txt', and set ALLOWED_HOSTS and TIME_ZONE in settings.py.  I like to remove the --noinput flags to see what's going on.  The last four commands are unnecessary, at least as of Mezzanine 3.0.9; just make sure you adjust httpd.conf accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since no one has answered my question yet, and since I realize django-cms is a better alternative for me, I decide to close this question by answering it myself. Thanks.